# Query Facebook wall feed as JSON/XML

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to code some kind of (perl) script which queries a Facebook wall feed[1]. This wall feed is public and do not need any authentification within browsers. Using Facebook Graph API I have to generate an personalisied access token to query the feed. This is not acceptable for me because other users have access to my private profile with this token.

That brings my to my question: Is it possible to gather this public wall feed without having an access token nor parse html (parse normal website)? So with JSON/XML...

[1] https://www.facebook.com/reifendirekt?sk=wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this isn't possible without "**any valid** `access_token` **or user** `access_token`".

You may however create application and use Application `access_token` (either `APP_ID|APP_SECRET` or retrieved from `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials`) for accessing `feed` connection of your page.

If you distribute that script than probably best way to use some kind of configuration file containing this private information which is not distributed with a script.

Comment: Thank you, Juicy Scripter. Bad to hear that but it's something which I have to deal with.